# Using the scala docs

Tags: scala

I'm trying to find a description of the Math methods in Scala

Using the doc reference :

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.package

Methods seems to be listed as "Value Members" . I just want to find a description of the methods within the scala.math package but this does'nt seem to be available at link above ?

What is difference between "Value Members" and methods ?

Comment: The distinction is values vs types. Other kinds of values are `val` and `object`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking at is an example of a "package object." Hence, all those methods on that "package" are implemented as methods on an object (which just so happens to also be the package things are contained within.) Scala allows by the following declaration to declare package object:

```
 package com.example

 package object foo{
   def lala(x: Int): Int = x + 1
 }
```

Wherein you'd access the `lala` via:

```
 import com.example.foo._

 >> lala(3)
 res0: 4
```

So to answer your question, there really is no different between a `def` in a package object and a `def` in any old object.

Comment: The ascii art here shows that scaladoc does some work to homogenize defs in package objects. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/scaladoc/scala/tools/nsc/doc/model/ModelFactory.scala#L558  Also worth mentioning that package objects were ambitious in conception: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html